# How to set max ppsize in R?

Tags: r

I am experiencing an error in R that says:

```
> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

I have learned through googling that I need to increase:

```
> --max-ppsize
```

[R-manual:Memory](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory.html)

This can only be set when starting R so I write the following in the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe --max-ppsize=5000000
```

The error still occurs. I am running a 1500R x 26000C dataset.

How do I solve this problem?

---

**Edit:**

The problem occurs in a standard SVM() function, where I pass a dataset of the size 600R x 26.000C. It does not happen when the dataset is 600R x 12.000C.

```
> model <- svm(TARGET ~ ., data = ds, type = "C-classification", kernel "linear", scale = TRUE, cost = c, cross = k)
```

Comment: Your max value is invalid. The largest you can input is `--max-ppsize=500000`

Comment: Elizion: Just tried your suggested correction. Still no effect...

Comment: Are you using R 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I would advise you take a look at this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767432/how-can-i-tell-when-my-dataset-in-r-is-going-to-be-too-large

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we we can see what you are trying to do. There might be problems in your code that leads to this memory issue.

Comment: I updated the question. The problem occurs in a SVM function and I am pretty sure it is due to data amount...

Comment: It definately seems that your data set is too large for svm. How big is the data set (in MB?) Is it sparse? It might be converted to sparse matrix if so. Another idea would be to run the svm command on a subset of the original dataset, e.g. first 1000 rows, and then find out what's the biggest subset of the data which still can be handled by svm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a similar problem and that the actual issue was related to expansion of formulas into a model matrix.  If you can get the data into that format without using formulas and then use the overload in the svm command (like many other models) that takes an X and y value instead, your probably may go away like mine did.

Comment: Do you have any workarounds for methods like logistic regression (glm) or ridge regression (glmnet)? It looks like a formula needs to be provided for these methods.

Comment: @Eric Czech This is the only solution that worked for my case.

Comment: @sma ?? `glmnet` only accepts X and y. Check `?glmnet`.

Answer (score 7):

My way to fix a problem similar to yours:

1. in the command-line, cd into the location of R progranm (e.g. C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64)
2. in the command-line, Rgui.exe --max-ppsize=500000
3. in the new open Rgui.exe, options("expressions"=20000)

Do the coding... NO original Error for me!!

Comment: This solution also worked by the solution i accepted was simpler and works directly in R studio :)

Answer (score 2):

The stack overflow might be a problem of too deep recursion, you might have a problem with a function calling itself recursively too many times, e.g. missing exit condition. In that case there's no point in increasing stack size, it will run out sooner or later anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I added some additional info to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 10 laptop, I ran into this same issue running a tSNE analysis on a 945 x 22123 `data.frame` with `Rtsne`. Even after following the steps above to increase the ppsize and expressions (with `Rstudio.exe` substituted for `Rgui.exe`), I still got: `> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow`

On another [thread](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/using-the-t-sne-algorithm-on-microarray-data-an-error-bonus) I found the recommendation to use a matrix instead of a `data.frame` because the Rtsne function will have to convert to matrix anyhow and thus hold both the `data.frame` and the converted `matrix` in memory simultaneously. The easy fix was to change from:

```
tsne1 <- Rtsne(df, dims = 2, pca = TRUE)
```

to:

```
tsne1 <- Rtsne(as.matrix(df), dims = 2, pca = TRUE)
```