# Change the max- ppsize in R and sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I R and sparkR I want to change the 'max-ppsize'.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf
page 93/105 there is a desciption for the command.

How exactly do I type it in when I have open the R or sparkR program on Ubuntu ? I couldnt find a clear description for it else where.

I have looked at the answer on
[How to set max ppsize in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728774/how-to-set-max-ppsize-in-r)

I can do it in R successfully but in I can't do it in SparkR.

I launch sparkR on ubuntu like this

```
cd /home/.../R/spark-1.4.0
```

and then I type

```
.bin/sparkR --max-ppsize=90000
```

But I get an error message: "log4j Warn No appenders could be found for logger"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set max ppsize in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728774/how-to-set-max-ppsize-in-r)

Comment: I can do it for R but when I do it for sparkR I get this message: "log4j Warn No appenders could be found for logger"