# I want to change --max-ppsize in Rstudio

Tags: r

I have read 
[How to set max ppsize in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728774/how-to-set-max-ppsize-in-r)
and I have the same problem. I am currently working in Rstudio and I need to set max ppsize to a greater value.

This is my approach:

```
   > setwd("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin")
   > R.exe --max-pp-size=500000
   Error in R.exe - -max - pp - size = 5e+05 : object 'R.exe' not found
```

Is this the right way to do it? I have no idea why I can not find the R.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you were writing this code into the R-console. But with "command line" its is meant what you upen under windows by searching for `cmd` (s. e.g. [this video for windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-Bnm9LxG6A) or [this for mac OS X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftJoIN_OADc) or [this for Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHFzr-akOas)).

Comment: The flag works for R now:
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin>R.exe --max-pp-size=500000
However it doesn't work for Rstudio, any ideas?
(C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin>rstudio.exe --max-pp-size=500000)