# Error in RStudio while running decision tree (mac)

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running a CART decision tree on a training set which I've tokenized using quanteda for a routine text analysis task. The resulting DFM from tokenizing was turned into a dataframe and appended with the class attribute I am predicting for.

Like many DFMs, the table is very wide (33k columns), but only contains about 5,500 rows of documents. Calling rpart on my training set returns a stack overflow error.

If it matters, to help increase the speed of calculations, I am using the doSNOW library so I can run the model on 3 out of 4 of my cores in parallel.

I've looked [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894977/i-want-to-change-max-ppsize-in-rstudio) but can't figure out how to do the equivalent on my mac workstation to see if the same solution would work for me. There is a chance that even if I increase the ppsize of RStudio, I may still run into this error.

So my question is how do I increase the maxppsize of RStudio **on a mac**, or more generally, how can I fix this stack overflow so I can run my model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found that macs don't have this same command line option since the mac version of RStudio uses all available memory by default.

So the way I fixed this is by decreasing the complexity of the task by reducing the sparsity. I cleaned the document-term matrix by removing all tokens that did not occur in at least 5% of the corpus. This was enough to take a matrix with 33k columns down to a much more manageable 3k columns while still leading to a highly representative DFM.